# My project's first run always freezes until the first gesture

Tags: flutter, dart

My App always freezes at the first run and doesn't respond once I do any gesture to it, it then takes about 1 second and starts working normally. I tried removing each widget separately to find which one is causing the freeze but no luck.

These are the 3 main files that I started my project with since the problem occurred.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notfound/darkThemeProvider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'configurations.dart';
import 'mainFrame.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  DarkThemeProvider themeProvider = DarkThemeProvider();
  bool loaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getThemeAsync();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getThemeAsync() async {
    await getCurrentAppTheme();
    setState(() {
      loaded = true;
    });
  }

  getCurrentAppTheme() async {
    themeProvider.darkTheme = await themeProvider.darkThemePreference.getTheme();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return !loaded ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : ChangeNotifierProvider<DarkThemeProvider>(
      create: (_){
        return themeProvider;
      },
      child: Consumer<DarkThemeProvider>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget? widget){
          return Sizer(
            builder:(context, orientation, deviceType){
              return MaterialApp(
                  theme: Styles.themeData(false, context),
                  darkTheme: Styles.themeData(true, context),
                  themeMode: themeProvider.darkTheme ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
                  home: Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context){
                      return MainFrame();
                    },
                  )
              );
            }
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

mainFrame.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notfound/mainPage.dart';
import 'package:notfound/routesGenerator.dart';
import 'package:notfound/topsPage.dart';
import 'package:notfound/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

import 'ProductPage.dart';
import 'base.dart';
import 'darkThemeProvider.dart';

class MainFrame extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainFrame({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainFrame> createState() => _MainFrameState();
}

class _MainFrameState extends State<MainFrame> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  late DarkThemeProvider provider;
  final GlobalKey<SideMenuState> _sideMenuKey = GlobalKey<SideMenuState>();
  Offset screenOffs = const Offset(0.0, 0.0);
  Offset screenDrag = const Offset(0.0, 0.0);
  bool sideMenuOpened = false;
  HeroController heroController = HeroController();
  final image = const AssetImage('assets/images/below.png');

  void _changeThemeMode() {
    setState(() {
      provider.darkTheme = !provider.darkTheme;
    });
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    final state = _sideMenuKey.currentState!;
    sideMenuOpened = !state.isOpened;
    if (state.isOpened) {
      state.closeSideMenu();
    } else {
      state.openSideMenu();
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      precacheImage(image, context).then(_markNeedsBuild);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
  void _markNeedsBuild([_]) {
    if(mounted) setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    provider = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return SideMenu(
      key: _sideMenuKey,
      background: Colors.blue,
      menu: buildMenu(),
      type: SideMenuType.slideNRotate,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          if (_sideMenuKey.currentState!.isOpened){
            toggleMenu();
          }
        },
        onPanStart: (details){
          screenDrag  = details.globalPosition;
        },
        onPanUpdate: (details){
          screenOffs = details.globalPosition;
        },
        onPanEnd: onPanEnd,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Flexible(flex: 1, child: IconButton(onPressed: (){
                  toggleMenu();
                }, icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.line_horizontal_3))),
                Flexible(flex: 2, child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'))),
                Flexible(flex: 1, child: IconButton(onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {

                  });
                }, icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: IgnorePointer(
            ignoring: sideMenuOpened,
            child: Navigator(
              key: navKey,
              initialRoute: '/',
              onGenerateInitialRoutes: (navState, initialRoute) {
                return [MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => mainPage(image: image,))];
              },
              onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.gen,
              observers: [heroController],
            ),
          ),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void onPanEnd(details){
    // print("start : ${screenDrag.dx} -> end: ${screenOffs.dx}");
    if (screenDrag.dx > 0.0 && screenDrag.dx < context.size!.width / 5){
      if ((screenOffs.dx - screenDrag.dx) < context.size!.width / 2){
        final absHeight = (screenOffs.dy - screenDrag.dy).abs();
        final absWidth =  (screenOffs.dx - screenDrag.dx).abs();
        if (absHeight < absWidth){
          if (!_sideMenuKey.currentState!.isOpened){
            toggleMenu();
          }
        }
      }
    }else if(screenDrag.dx > context.size!.width / 3){
      if ((screenOffs.dx - screenDrag.dx) < 0){
        if (_sideMenuKey.currentState!.isOpened){
          toggleMenu();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Widget buildMenu() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: const [
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  radius: 22.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Text(
                  "Hello, John Doe",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              toggleMenu();
              navKey.currentState?.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
            },
            leading: const Icon(Icons.home, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            title: const Text("Home"),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            dense: true,
          ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              toggleMenu();
              navKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/profile');
            },
            leading: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.profile_circled,
                size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            title: const Text("Account"),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            dense: true,

            // padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {},
            leading: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,
                size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            title: const Text("Cart"),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            dense: true,

            // padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {},
            leading:
            const Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart_fill, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            title: const Text("Favorites"),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            dense: true,

            // padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              _changeThemeMode();
              toggleMenu();
            },
            leading: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.moon_fill,
                size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            title: Text(provider.darkTheme ? "Light Mode" : "Dark Mode"),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            dense: true,

            // padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

mainPage.dart:

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notfound/bottomsPage.dart';
import 'package:notfound/topsPage.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

import 'configurations.dart';

class mainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ImageProvider? image;
  mainPage({Key? key, this.image}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<mainPage> createState() => _mainPageState();
}

class _mainPageState extends State<mainPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  late TabController tabController;
  ValueNotifier<bool> loaded = ValueNotifier(false);
  late ImageProvider image;
  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.image != null){
      image = widget.image!;
    }else{
      image = const AssetImage('assets/images/below.png');
    }
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        tabController.animateTo(1);
        print('setted');
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  fixTabIssue() async{
    await isBuildFinished(loaded);
    print('ran');
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10)).then((value) {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loaded.value = true;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Hero(
                    tag: 'unique130',
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/photos/photo1.jpg')),
              ),
            ),
            TopsPage(),
            BottomsPage(),
          ],
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 3.h,
          right: 10.w,
          left: 10.w,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.sp),
              color: Colors.blue.shade800,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  offset: Offset(2, 2), // changes position of shadow
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: TabBar(
                indicatorColor: Colors.green,
                indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                indicatorWeight: 5.sp,
                indicator:  BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.green, BlendMode.srcATop),
                        image: image )
                ),
                labelColor: Colors.green,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.w),
                isScrollable: true,
                controller: tabController,
                tabs:[
                  FittedBox(child: Text('LATEST', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.sp),)),
                  FittedBox(child: Text('TOPS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.sp))),
                  FittedBox(child: Text('BOTTOMS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.sp))),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to remove each widget separately:

- Theme
- Sidebar
- TabBar

Comment: Probably this is the fastest solution I had, just adding this line at the beginning of the main() function fixed my issue:

 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();